# QGIS coloring layers with same colours

Tags: qgis, polygon, color

I am using QGIS 2.14.3.
I have a Layer with different attribute string columns. I've colored one layer for the first column with properties->style and random colours (about 900 different colours). I duplicated the layer and colored it for the second column.

In the first and second column are the same names, but they are differently distributed and not all rows in the second column are filled. Now I want to color the second column so that the same names have the same colour as in the first column.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the style section just choose your other column for the style options but dont reclassify. just click apply and it should work!

Comment: That is a nice, neat trick! :)